# adding the functionality of user counter in the servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

I have developed a servlet below in which the logic is that If name is equal to saral saxena then it moves to next page otherwise not , I am posting below my code also , I want one change is that It should also you are visitor Number also such that if two different users  from different browser hit the same url then for the second one it should show that you are visitor No. 2 .  below is my current piece of code..

```
  package trial;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class SendRedirectServlet
 */
public class SendRedirectServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
            response)throws ServletException, IOException {
        //System.out.println("*************");

        response.setContentType("text/html");
          PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
          String name = request.getParameter("username");
          pw.println("<br> this output is generated by a simple servlet.");
         String password = request.getParameter("password");
          if(name.equals("saral")&& password.equals("saxena")){
              response.sendRedirect("/ValidUserServlet");
          }
          else{
          pw.println("u r not a valid user");
          }

        }
}
```

the other servlet is ...

```
    ackage trial;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class ValidUserServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


         PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
          pw.println("Welcome to roseindia.net " + " ");
          pw.println("how are you");


    }


}
```

and my web.xml rite now is...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

  <servlet>
   <servlet-name>s1</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>trial.SendRedirectServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>s1</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/SendRedirectServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
   <servlet-name>s2</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>trial.ValidUserServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>s2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ValidUserServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>home.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

and finally my html page is ...

```
    <html>

<head>
<title>New Page 1</title>
</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action="/SendRedirectServlet">
  <p>Enter your name&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <input type="text" name="username" size="20"/></p>
  <p>Enter your password&nbsp; <input type="text" name="password"
   size="20"/></p>
  <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1"/></p>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

The snapshot of the project structure is..

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/707/49690689.jpg/

Please advise how to add that functionality of you are visitor No.

guys please advise.

Comment: welcome to roseindia.net? Come on, dont just copy past code you find in Google....

Answer (score 1):

**1.** The request which hits the container is **NOT per User**, BUT **One per Request, even if its from the same browser.**

**2.** `service()` **method is called Everytime a request comes and hits the Container**, so place a **counter inside service() method to count the number of user visited your site.**

**////////////EDITED////////////////**

Now as i am showing the example of **HttpServlet** the method will be either `doGet` or `doPost` **instead of** `service()`. **Here it is** `doGet()`

**The below is an example from roseindia.com**

```
public class CounterServlet extends HttpServlet{
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
  HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException {
  HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
  response.setContentType("text/html");
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  Integer count = new Integer(0);
  String head;
  if (session.isNew()) {
  head = "This is the New Session";
  } else {
  head = "This is the old Session";
  Integer oldcount =(Integer)session.getValue("count"); 
  if (oldcount != null) {
  count = new Integer(oldcount.intValue() + 1);
  }
  }
  session.putValue("count", count);
  out.println("<HTML><BODY BGCOLOR=\"#FDF5E6\">\n" +
  "<H2 ALIGN=\"CENTER\">" + head + "</H2>\n" + 
  "<TABLE BORDER=1 ALIGN=CENTER>\n"
  + "<TR BGCOLOR=\"#FFAD00\">\n" 
  +"  <TH>Information Type<TH>Session Count\n" 
  +"<TR>\n" +" <TD>Total Session Accesses\n" +
  "<TD>" + count + "\n" +
  "</TABLE>\n" 
  +"</BODY></HTML>" );
  }
}
```

Comment: Vivek could you please post the updated code , that will make understanding more clear

Comment: shouldn't the counter part be synchronized ?

Comment: @ a.u.r Ya i think you are right... but as i said this code is from roseindia.com, and its a working code, i didnt edited. it...

Comment: +1, this is of interest to me :-) I will learn something from the code :-)